Power BI RankEQ Values Always 1
I am working on ranking clients based using the Rank.EQ Dax Equation. I am running into an issue where the rank is always 1. Here is the set up:
Rank.EQ measure:
Pull Through Ranking = RANK.EQ(Fact_ClientPullThrough_RptOps[Current Pull Through],Dim_Client[Pull Through],DESC)

Dim_Client[Pull Through] measure:
Pull Through = [Current Pull Through]

Current Pull Through measure:
Current Pull Through = CALCULATE([UW Requested Pull Through], PARALLELPERIOD(Dim_Date[Current_DT],0,MONTH)) 

Dim_Client is joined to Fact_ClientPullThrough_RptOps. The values in the client id column in Dim_Client are all unique.Also, the pull through measure on the fact pull through table is for the current month so not every client in the dim client table will have a value, some are null.
Thank you for helping and let me know if I need to clarify more.
Ideally I would want to adjust the ranking where the client status is active and only rank based on active clients. But I want to fix the base DAX Equations first.

Sounds like your evaluation context contains one record, so you need to use ALL() or REMOVEFILTERS() to expand the evaluation context to contain all the pullthrough records you need in order to determine the rank

I went ahead and added ALL to the second argument in the Rank.EQ formula: Pull Through Ranking = RANK.EQ(Fact_ClientPullThrough_RptOps[Current Pull Through],all(Fact_PlazaBroker_BACTA[Pull Through]),DESC) However I get back the The RANK.EQ function only accepts a column reference as the argument number 2 error. When I try to put ALL on the first argument the intellisense does not recognize the measure

Is there a reason you can't just use RANKX()?

The pull through values are repeated often, especially with the measure being a percentage and their being a few thousand clients. The Ultimate end goal is to assign a rank that is not equal for each client so that I can bucket them in groups of top 25%, middle 50%, and bottom 50%

Oh, okay. Maybe this will help:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/rankx-on-multiple-columns-with-dax-and-power-bi/
(Alberto Ferrari explaining how to do tie-breaking when using RANKX)
